# Storing and reusing results of functions in Insert/Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a trigger, which basically takes value of `in_address` (a varchar field) and, depending on whether the value is numeric or not, sets some values differently. The select below shows how I get my values.

```
    INSERT INTO ........... --irrelevant names
    SELECT 
        case when ISNUMERIC(in_address)=1 then convert( tinyint, left( in_address,1 ) ) else 9 end,
        case when ISNUMERIC(in_address)=1 then xlat_byte else 9 end,
        case when ISNUMERIC(in_address)=1 then xlat_bit else 9 end,
        case when ISNUMERIC(in_address)=1 then 'xlat_' else '' end+in_address,
    FROM [in],##in_xlat 
    WHERE (ISNUMERIC(in_address)=1 AND in_xlat_address = right(in_address, 2)) or ISNUMERIC(in_address)=0 AND in_xlat_address = 1
```

I am wondering if there is a way to store the result of first `ISNUMERIC(in_address)` call and reuse them rather than recalculating each time.

Comment: Do it before your insert command.

Comment: Results of `ISNUMERIC` are row specific so I need to recalculate on each row. `in_address` is a varchar field, so some rows might have numeric values stored, while others might have a string of characters.

Comment: You could use a cte for such things

Comment: You could do a union all query.  The top half would be for the numeric values and the bottom half for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OUTER APPLY like this:

```
  INSERT INTO ........... --irrelevant names
    SELECT 
        case when numbers.isnumber=1 then convert( tinyint, left( in_address,1 ) ) else 9 end,
        case when  numbers.isnumber=1 then xlat_byte else 9 end,
        case when  numbers.isnumber=1 then xlat_bit else 9 end,
        case when  numbers.isnumber=1 then 'xlat_' else '' end+in_address,
    FROM [in],##in_xlat 
      outer apply (select isnumeric(in_address) as isnumber from [in] in2 where in2.keyfields = [in].keyfields) as numbers
    WHERE (numbers.isnumber=1 AND in_xlat_address = right(in_address, 2)) ornumbers.isnumber=0 AND in_xlat_address = 1
```

Comment: Neat trick! After a little bit of debugging, got it to work and do exactly what I need it to.

Had to replace `[in], ##in_xlat` with `##in_xlat, [in]` (apparantelly, since `[in]` is used in outer apply,it had to be left of apply statement.).

Comment: The code was untested, should have added a default 'use at your own risk' disclaimer :)